# Listview separator JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery Mobile Flat UI Theme. It's great but i want to add a separator between each listview .

Here is the listview :

[image: Listview]

Which code I have to add in my .css file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want list style css to separate each list.

Check DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/2qgtA/1/

Add this css.

```
ul li.ui-li {
    border-top:1px solid #ccc !important;
}
ul li.ui-li-divider{
    border-top:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

Just add this **`li`** element before every classic **`listview`** element:

#### Example:

```
<li data-role="list-divider">Some text here</li>
```

### Solution 2

Or it can be done automatically if you add an attribute **`data-autodividers="true"`** to your listview **`ul`** element.

#### Example:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Caleb Booth</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Christopher Adams</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Culver James</a></li>
</ul>
```

### Solution 3

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/JHDsq/

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#index', function(){ 
    $( "#mylistview li" ).each(function() {        
        $(this).before('<li data-role="list-divider"></li>');
    });
});
```

This solution will add an divider to every existing **`li`** element. Also take a notice at an attribute **`data-divider-theme="a"`**, it will create black deviders.

Comment: Thanks but i want separator BETWEEN each listview. like Jquery Mobile's listview . I just want the black stripe.

Comment: Take a look at my Solution 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li>Acura</li>
  <li>Audi</li>
  <li>BMW</li>
</ul>
```